# Grok pattern works in Grok debugger but not in logstash config

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

My log:

```
(49087) Login incorrect (eap_peap: TLS Alert write:fatal:decode error): [johndoe] (from client WIFI-Control-Dev port 13 cli bb-41-e2-1c-12-12)
```

The grok pattern I use:

```
\(%{NOTSPACE:removed}\) %{DATA:AUTHWAY} (?:\(%{DATA:radius_reason}\))?: (?:\[%{DATA:username}\]) \(from client %{NOTSPACE:radius_client} port %{INT:radius_port}(?: cli %{NOTSPACE:radius_cli})?(?: via %{DATA:radius_via})?\)
```

This matches and works perfectly in grok debugger but when I use the same pattern in my logstash config, it doesn't work.

The AUTHWAY field is coming as:

```
"AUTHWAY" => "Login incorrect (eap: Failed continuing EAP PEAP (25) session. EAP sub-module failed)",
```

What I need is `Login incorrect` and `(eap: Failed continuing EAP PEAP (25) session. EAP sub-module failed)` as separate field.

Can any one say what is the difference and how can I make the grok pattern work in logstash config too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. So I'm posting it because it could help anyone.

This is the grok pattern I used and it works both in grok debugger and in server.

```
\(%{DATA:removed}\) %{DATA:AUTHWAY}(?::)? (?:\((.*?)\):)?%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:username}\] \(from client %{NOTSPACE:radius_client} port %{INT:radius_port}(?: cli %{NOTSPACE:radius_cli})?(?: via %{DATA:radius_via})?\)
```

Here I used `(?::)? (?:\((.*?)\):)?%{SPACE}` instead of `(?:\(%{DATA:radius_reason}\))?:`